# Criação de Masks com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu preciso de criar máscaras para uns `inputs` que eu tenho no código, e já tinha perguntado sobre isso, mas penso que o post ficou desatualizado e então ficou "esquecido". No entanto o que tinha conseguido com aquele post foi:

**HTML:**

Dentro do `<HEAD>`:

```
        <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Dentro do `<BODY>`:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Escreva o número de processo aqui..." required maxlength="5">
```

**Javascript depois de `</HTML>`:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").mask("99999");
        });
```

e mesmo assim não funciona. já tentei criar uma nova página para testar esta função mas também não funcionou. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que se passa?

Comment: Você tem que carregar primeiro o jquery, depois o masked input e por último o seu document.ready

Comment: Como assim? o jquery, voce esta a falar das bibliotecas? depois o script?

Comment: Isso, dá uma olhada na resposta e tenta alterar a ordem do carregamento dos arquivos JS

Answer (score 2):

O problema ocorre devido a falha na ordem de carregamento dos scripts. Faça a seguinte alteração:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

Edit: montei um fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/61tok014/ e aparentemente funcionou.

Comment: tentei o que falaram, mas continua a não funcionar. não ha outra maneira de fazer mascaras?

Comment: Faço todas as minhas masks com esse plugin sem problema. Tem certeza que os arquivos estão carregando.?

Comment: Eu uso muitos plugins, para obter icons do font-awesome, modals de bootstrap etc..será por causa disso? devo meter as mask primeiro?

Comment: Que você tem que colocar primeiro o jquery depois os plugins eu tenho certeza

Comment: Eu uso o sublime text, e costumo guardar os projetos com UTF-8 with BOM faz diferença?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui! Alterei

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

para

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda